# Returning total percentage within a group

Tags: sql

Using this sample database: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_avg

I am trying to create a table that returns the percentage of orders per category, for each country. So it would look ideally something like this:

```
Country   CategoryName  Num_of_orders  % of orders
Argentina  Confections       1            0.50
Argentina   Produce          1            0.50
Austria    Beverages         5            0.17
Austria    Condiments        6            0.21
```

So since Argentina has only had two orders, Confections will be 50%, and so will produce.

So far the closest I have gotten is returning a percentage of the total order count, but ignoring the countries.

```
SELECT c.country, ca.categoryname, count(o.orderid) as Num_of_orders, 
    count(*)/(select 1.0*count(*) from orders) as percentage
from orders as o
join customers as c on c.customerid = o.customerid
join orderdetails as od on od.orderid = o.orderid
join products as p on p.productid = od.productid
join categories as ca on ca.categoryid = p.categoryid
group by 1, 2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it works fine..what is the issue that you feel is there

Comment: I'm trying to get the percentage of orders by category for each individual country. So in the ideal situation, it would return:
Argentina | Confections | 1 | 0.50 (50%)
as opposed to:
Argentina | Confections | 1 | 0.0051 ( >0%)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That `GROUP BY 1, 2` isn't ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the following, which selects the count by the country in the subquery, rather than the count of all orders.

```
SELECT c.country, ca.categoryname, count(o.orderid) as Num_of_orders, 
    count(*)/(select 1.0*count(*) from orders o2 join customers c2 on c2.customerid = o2.customerid join orderdetails od2 on od2.orderid = o2.orderid WHERE c2.country=c.country) as percentage
from orders as o
join customers as c on c.customerid = o.customerid
join orderdetails as od on od.orderid = o.orderid
join products as p on p.productid = od.productid
join categories as ca on ca.categoryid = p.categoryid
group by 1, 2
```

This version works on your sample database, but depending on what database your real query is being run against, you might consider counting over a partition instead of the subquery, or at least using a common table expression to avoid writing some of joins twice like I've done here.